# Suppose $(s_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers. There exists a real number $s$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=s$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

prove the following by using subsequences which is by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Suppose ($s_n$) is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers. There exists a real number s such that lim n→∞$s_n$ = s

here some of my works

We have |$s_n$ −s| = |$s_n −s_nk + s($_nk)$ −s$| ≤ |$s_n −s_nk$|+|$s_nk −s$|. how we can choose n and $n_k$ s.t $n_k$>= k

could you please help me how can I complete it ?

Comment: If the sequence is Cauchy it is also convergent sequence.

Comment: You're putting the cart before the horse.  You can't write down $s$ until you know what it might be.  However, the conclusion of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem might be relevant.

Comment: @arberavdullahu: That statement is equivalent to this proposition; I believe the exercise is to prove it.

Comment: Part of the proof is to show that this limit is well defined, i.e. that this element $s$ actually exists.

Comment: If you write down the definition of cauchy sequence maybe you can get an idea on how to use Bolzano-Weierstrass

Answer (score 3):

Hint/Sketch: You already realized that Bolzano Weirstrass is relevant.

What are the hypotheses for the theorem to hold? You need boundedness of your sequence, so start by proving that Cauchy sequences are bounded.

Next, once you have convergence along a subsequence to some limit $s$, what does the Cauchy condition tell you about the other terms in the sequence and how they relate to this subsequence?